# Jquery JScrollPane causes Error in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jscrollpane

I'm doing my first site using jquery and I added the jscrollPane plugin.

Everything fine in Firefox and Safari, but in IE (obviously) it gives me a problem I can't figure out:

When I call the "jscrollPane" function, it causes a fault in jquery and it mess up my page! (obviously only in IE)

If you want to see the page here's the link:
http://www.klaber.it/demo

Just click on "PRODOTTI" and then click the first submenu voice...
I figured out with some tests that the ! on IE status bar throw an error just when jscrollPane is called...

It's driving me crazy...
Thanks for help.
Dario

Answer (score 3):

You have this code in your myfunctionNew.js file

```
$("#datiProdotto").load("prodotto.asp?myPNum=" + showScheda, function() {
    $('#slider').show();
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'sliceDown', //Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        slices: 1,
        animSpeed: 500, //Slide transition speed
        pauseTime: 4000,
        startSlide: 0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)
        directionNav: false, //Next & Prev
        directionNavHide: true, //Only show on hover
        controlNav: true, //1,2,3...
        controlNavThumbs: false, //Use thumbnails for Control Nav
        /*controlNavThumbsFromRel:false, //Use image rel for thumbs
        controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', //Replace this with...
        controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', //...this in thumb Image src
        keyboardNav:true, //Use left & right arrows
        pauseOnHover:true, //Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance:false, //Force manual transitions
        captionOpacity:0.8, //Universal caption opacity
        beforeChange: function(){},
        afterChange: function(){},
        slideshowEnd: function(){} //Triggers after all slides have been shown*/
    });
});
```

You need to remove the trailing comma from the end of this line.

```
controlNavThumbs: false,
```

That is the first error I've come across. There may be more after it.